# Allow a user to sort a list of nodes for the purpose of discovery

Tags: views

I've got a list of nodes (restaurants) that each have the following fields: name, price, opening hours, location.

I'm looking for a sort module that allows users to input their desired price range, time they'd like to dine, and location and then the nodes will be sorted in order of most relevant to least relevant.

I'm able to do this with filters, but would prefer a ranking system, rather than a filtering one.

Do you know of any modules out there that can help with this?

Cheers!

Comment: Have you looked at the Search modules, with Facets?